# Merging rows in a dataframe depending on another column

Tags: python, string, dataframe, join, pandas-groupby

I have extracted a pdf into a dataframe and would like to merge the rows if column B is the same speaker :

From :

```
  Index     Column B     Column C 
   1       'I am going'    Speaker A 
   2       'to the zoo'    Speaker A
   3       'I am going'    Speaker B 
   4       'home      '    Speaker B
   5       'I am going'    Speaker A 
   6       'to the park'   Speaker A
```

To :

```
  Index     Column B                    Column C 
   1       'I am going to the zoo '    Speaker A 
   2       'I am going home'           Speaker B
   3       'I am going to the park'    Speaker A
```

I tried using groupby but the order is important in the context of a pdf which is a speech.

Comment: according to your ques speaker should only have one row and the speech should get combined maintaing the order, so how can you show two diff rows for speaker A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` + `agg` after creating a series identifying when Column C changes:

```
res = df.assign(key=df['Column C'].ne(df['Column C'].shift()).cumsum())\
        .groupby('key').agg({'Column C': 'first', 'Column B': ' '.join})\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

   key   Column C                    Column B
0    1  Speaker A   'I am going' 'to the zoo'
1    2  Speaker B   'I am going' 'home      '
2    3  Speaker A  'I am going' 'to the park'
```

Note the output has quotation marks, as per the input you have supplied. These won't show if the strings are defined without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and `agg`, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
data = {'col1': [1,1,2,2,3], 'col2': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bag', 'bat']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
aggregated = df.groupby('col1').agg(lambda x: reduce(lambda s1, s2: s1 + s2, x))
print(aggregated)
```

Will produce the following output:

```
col1 col2
0     1  foo
1     1  bar
2     2  baz
3     2  bag
4     3  bat

        col2
col1
1     foobar
2     bazbag
3        bat
```

Comment: using groupby will not retain the order of the text, I would need to group the text in order

Comment: This anyways would not give the expected output. Look for `Speaker A` expected result.